# Timeout when showing NSSavePanel

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssavepanel

When showing an `NSSavePanel` while the app is in background I get the following error:

```
RVS:__54-[NSRemoteSavePanel _runOrderingOperationWithContext:]_block_invoke_0319 : Timeout occured while waiting for the window
Remote Window Controller requested NSRequestRetryActivateSharedwindow...
```

Also, the panel doesn't appear and `runModal` returns `NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton`.

The app is sandboxed. This is the code that creates the panel:

```
NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
NSInteger result = [panel runModal];
if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
{
    // Do something
}
```

What might be the problem?

If the app is in the foreground the panel is shown without any error.

Comment: damn ^^ this is hard... mhm not in a block... in main thread? I guess so... WHEN do you call this?

Comment: Main thread. I already checked in the debugger, just in case.

Comment: yip and WHEN? before appWilllFinishLaunching - from inside awakeFromNib?

Comment: Gets called in a delegate method of the app delegate, after a long-running background operation finishes. The method is called in the main thread.

Comment: and do you somehow block the main thread after the call somehow -- so that the window cannot be shown? some sleep ^^ or for(i<1000000000) or some calculation?

Comment: Nope. I only call stopAnimation on a progress indicator before, but I removed that to test and it still fails.

Comment: and after the call to runModal?

Comment: There's nothing after the `beginWithCompletionHandler:` call.

Comment: Clarified that the app is sandboxed. Also simplified the example, as the problem can be also reproduced with `runModal`.

Comment: are you running something else modal? or does the runloop not run by any chance?

Comment: Nope. The only "odd" thing is that it only happens when the app is not in the foreground.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to enable the appropriate entitlements. In this case, check that "User Selected File" is not set to "No Access".

Comment: It's set to Read/Write access.

Answer (score 1):

For the "User selected file" entitlement of the Entitlement section from Summary tab of target setting should be set to "Read/Write" access.

Comment: The questioner already said that it is set to read/write. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060214/timeout-when-showing-nssavepanel#comment19462600_14076740

Comment: Sorry Peter Hosey, I did not observe. Even i had faced same issue, By setting "Read/Write" access its been resolved